# Predictive model on categorical variable with high cardinality

Tags: r, regression, many-categories

So I have a categorical variable with ~ 8000 types (or levels, or cardinality). The dataset is rather large (a couple million records). Most machine learning techniques are failing do to memory limits on my computer, so I think an approach may be to run a loop and do individual regressions for each category step by step. Is there an easy way to do this in R? So for example, if the category was States in America, I would like 1 regression model for Virginia, 1 regression model for Texas, 1 regression model for Vermont, ect.

Any other ideas for dealing with a very large categorical variable with a very large cardinality?

Comment: Your general references to "machine learning," "regressions," and states suggest you need to be more specific in order to be understood properly.  What are you trying to do?  What role does this categorical variable play in your analysis?  (Is it a predictor or something to be predicted, for instance?)  How many other variables do you have?  Does the categorical variable have any kind of additional structure (such as an inherent order)?

Comment: They are not general references, you are mistaken. I'm using straight linear regression because my target variable in continuous, and I did not specify ordinal variables because it's only categorical. The amount of other variables is not significant (~ 5 or 10).

Comment: Please explain, then, why you refer to "machine learning techniques."  Is your question about how to perform a regression in which one of the independent variables is a factor with 8000 levels, there are no more than ten other independent variables involved, and you have a few million records, or is it more than that? Because there are differences between doing one regression or a large number of separate regressions, it would also help for you to describe your categorical variable and provide more information about the dependent variable.